# RPM Spec file - how to get rpm package location in %pre script

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am working with RPM package manager for about a month now. Currently I want to use rpm -U to upgrade already existing content from previous RPM execution but I need to know the rpm package location on the file system.

The only way I can think of is searching whole file system for rpm name in %pre script but I would really like to avoid that option. Is there any way to get the path of the rpm package (package can be anywhere on the system) as a variable inside the spec file (%pre and %post script). Hope I explained my issue clearly enough.

Any help or proposal is welcome.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly here? Why do you want this information? Are the files in question not packaged files?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one location (or path) where a package is installed,
so I'm not sure what you are asking.

The files that are installed by a installed rpm package called "foo"
can be displayed with
    rpm -ql foo
There is no common prefix on the paths except "/" in general.